# GITLAB WebSite Issue content Link Problem

Tags: gitlab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fjt9M.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loHu1.png)
I would like to install GITLAB and register and check issues during testing.
The registration is successful, but the URL is changed to confirm, so it does not appear on the screen.
If you are having this problem, please help.

thank you

I'm new to GITLAB and need some help.